# C++ type constraint using stream I/O fails if prototype is local

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

In the MCVE below, C++ has no trouble identifying that `int`s may be read or printed with stream I/O. But it thinks `A`s can't be, despite the prototypes for `<<` and `>>`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
concept Readable = requires(std::istream& in, T& t)
{
    in >> t;
};

template<typename T>
concept Printable = requires(std::ostream& out, T t)
{
    out << t;
};

int main()
{
    class A {};
    ostream& operator<< (ostream&, const A&);
    istream& operator>> (istream&, A&);

    std::cout << Readable<int> << Printable<int> << '\n';
    std::cout << Readable<A>   << Printable<A>   << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
11
00
```

If I make the prototypes and the class global, the problem is fixed (it prints `11`, not `00`, for the 2nd line of output).

Obviously I'd make prototypes global normally. But I don't see how scoping rules let the constraint know where it was defined, as long as it *is* defined.  Why doesn't it work when the prototypes are local?

Answer (score 3):

In both expressions -- `in >> t` and `out << t` -- `t` is a *dependent* name, which means the name lookup procedure for `operator>>` and `operator<<` is deferred until `T` is known (e.g., the first occurence of `Readable<A>` and `Printable<A>`, where `T=A`).

At this point, the compiler can perform non-ADL lookup (from the context of template definition) and ADL lookup.

For non-ADL lookup, it finds no matching declaration of `operator>>` and `operator<<` preceeding the concepts definitions.

For ADL lookup, it considers associated namespaces, in particular, the namespace of `A`. Class `A`, however, is locally defined inside function `main()`, and for that:

[[class.local]/p1](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.local#1):

> A class can be declared within a function definition; such a class is called a local class. The name of a local class is local to its enclosing scope. The local class is in the scope of the enclosing scope, [...]

Although the name `A` is local to `main()`, the class itself lives in the namespace enclosing `main()` - the global scope.

This means that in ADL, the compiler can look for the operators inside the scope of `A` but also in the global scope. However, for the two operator declarations the following rule applies:

[[basic.link]/p7](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#7):

> When a block scope declaration of an entity with linkage is not found to refer to some other declaration, then that entity is a member of the innermost enclosing namespace. However such a declaration **does not introduce** the member name in its namespace scope.

A function declaration by default has external linkage. Hence, neither operator is visible for name lookup, and the concepts are not satisfied.